# What is the scope of React Context?

Tags: reactjs

I am not clear on where `Context` can be created in a React app. Can I create context anywhere in the component tree, and if so, is that context only scoped to children of where it is created? Or is Context inherently global?

Where in the documentation can I find this?

Case: I'm reusing a component multiple times on a page and would like to use context to handle data for sub-components, but that context needs to be unique to each sub-tree.

Comment: The context is not global, unless you create it in the root component. Typically, contexts for theme etc are created globally. The idea is to lift the context up only until that level where any child element actually needs it.

Comment: I think @HarshaVenkatram means the context only effects children of the context provider, so its *not* global unless its in the root component

Comment: I got this from the official documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: From my point of view you could use the context api when you need to provied data to a deeply nested component. E.g. you have a component that represents some page of your application with some kind of a get request that fetches all the needed data for that page. If this page has a lot of sub components with a lot of subsubcomponents and you dont want to push those data through multiple layers of components than you could use the context. And as already mentioned you could use this also for theming your components.

Comment: Anyway, the context api is used by react-redux, react-router and many other libraries to provide some global data.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are 2 separate things: The context object, and the context provider.

The context object is created once globally (with an optional default value, which is global if no provider was passed from a component parent):

```js
const FontContext = createContext('Courier');
```

While a context provider actually passes down its own local override of the context, which only applies to its children:

```js
<FontContext.Provider value='Consolas'>
  {children}
</FontContext.Provider>
```

The interesting part is that contexts cascade:

```js
<>
  <MyFontConsumer /> // value is 'Courier', the default
  <FontContext.Provider value='Consolas'>
    <MyFontConsumer /> // value is 'Consolas'
    <FontContext.Provider value='TimesRoman'>
      <MyFontConsumer /> // value is 'TimesRoman'
    </FontContext.Provider>
    <MyFontConsumer /> // value is 'Consolas'
  </FontContext.Provider>
</>
```

To consume the context in your component you can use the `useContext()` hook, (you can use the special `<FontContext.Consumer>` component or `MyClassComponent.contextType` instead) which requires you to pass the same object.

My preferred way to avoid having to pass around the context object is to keep them all in the same component and export a custom hook:

```js
const FontContext = createContext('Courier')

export function FontProvider({value, children}) {
  return <FontContext.Provider value={value}>
    {children}
  </FontContext.Provider>
}

export function useFont() {
  return useContext(FontContext)
}
```

Now you can use it in your component:

```js
import {FontProvider, useFont} from './FontProvider'

function App() {
  const font = useFont() // value is 'Courier', the default

   return <FontProvider value='TimesRoman'>
      <MyChild />
   </FontProvider>
}

function MyChild() {
  const font = useFont() // value is 'TimesRoman'
  ...
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the information I was looking for, thank you. I was trying to figure out if I could reproduce the cascading nature of CSS variables for a react native project (In which CSS variables aren't available with the same functionality)

Answer (score 3):

> I am not clear on where `Context` can be created in a React app. Can I create context anywhere in the component tree?

A context object can technically be created anywhere with `createContext`, but to actually set the value to something other than the default you need a provider component. The context will be available via its consumer or the `useContext` hook in any child components of the provider.

> Is that context only scoped to children of where it is created?

If by "created" you mean where the provider is located, yes. However with the new context API you can set a default value, even without a provider.

> Or is Context inherently global?

No not inherently, though contexts are often placed within or above the app's root component to become global for all practical purposes.

> Where in the documentation can I find this?

- [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)
- [useContext hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

> Case: I'm reusing a component multiple times on a page and would like to use context to handle data for sub-components, but that context needs to be unique to each sub-tree.

As far as I understand, you have two options here:

1. Use a single context with different providers overriding it in sub-trees
2. Have a different context for each sub-tree

Comment: The important point here is that contexts cascade. If a context was provided in a child component it will have higher precedence over the one at a higher level.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question. I'd like to share something about the scope of the context especially.

##### Context

Context actually is a "global" idea, because at the time you create it, it's not attached to any fiber/component.

```
  const UserContext = React.createContext()
  export default UserContext
```

That's why it's normally exported right away. Why? Since all providers and consumers need to access it in different files under normal conditions. Although you can put them in a same file, that really doesn't show off the context nature. It's made to hold a "global" value that is persisted for the entire application. The underlying `value` is only storing a temporary one as the scope input argument described below. The real value is hidden behind the scene, because it keeps changing depending on the scope.

##### Scope

Context might be created long before the hook. There's no other way for React to send a data into certain distance deeper without showing up in the props. And a context is designed similar to a function, internally React uses a stack to pop/push context as it enters or leaves a provider. Therefore you'll see similar behavior when the same context provider is nested like below.

```
const Branch = ({ theme1, theme2 }) => {
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={theme1}>
      // A. value = theme1
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={theme2}>
        // B. value = theme2
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
      // C. value = theme1
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

If you treat each `ThemeContext` as a function with input argument `value`, then it's clear what are the values for locations `A`, `B` and `C`. In a way, a context is no different as a function :) This is also a good example to show you the prop `value` isn't the same value that the context `ThemeContext` is tracking, because otherwise you'll end up with a fixed value, either `theme1` or `theme2`. Behind the scene, there's a global mechanism :)

NOTES:

Context is designed to be very powerful, however due to the over-rendering issue, it's never reached to that level. But i guess there's no other replacement in React to share variables, therefore there's tendency that it'll become popular again, especially with the introduction of `useContextSelector` under proposal. I put some explanation to above in a blog here, https://windmaomao.medium.com/react-context-is-a-global-variable-b4b049812028