# How to efficiently pass props in nested components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say there are nested components, where data is passed from top to root, but only root component needs the data, how to deal with this more efficiently? Check the following example:

```
const Myform = () => {
    return (
        <Section title={'Nested component'} />
    )
}

const Section = ({title}) => {
    return (
        <Card title={title} />
    )
}

const Card = ({title}) => {
    return (
        <Title title={title} />
    )
}

const Title = ({title}) => {
    return (
        <h2>{title}</h2>
    )
}
```

`Myform` passes `title` data to `Section`, then passes to `Card`, then passes to root component `Title`, where data is only needed in `Title` component. The 2 middle components only pass data. I can see two problems:

1. Each middle component needs to accept `title`, but has no use of `title` at all;
2. If more middle components are needed, each of them needs to repeat the same process.

In fact only `Myform` and `Title` need to know the data. Is there a more efficient way to deal with this kind of scenario?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the scope of React Context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62707579/what-is-the-scope-of-react-context)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the Title component at the top and pass that down instead of the props. This is what [Facebook recommends here](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) in their docs on Composition vs Inheritance

EG:

```
const Myform = () => {
    return (
        <Section Title={<Title title='Nested component' />} />
    )
}

const Section = ({Title}) => {
    return (
        <Card Title={Title} />
    )
}

const Card = ({Title}) => {
    return (
        <Title />
    )
}

const Title = ({title}) => {
    return (
        <h2>{title}</h2>
    )
}
```

In this example with so many levels it doesn't work that great - in that case the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) might be better

Comment: whats `<Section title=` small title here with, gettin `const Section = ({Title})` capital Title here